# Windows Phone - binding to a list of objects then adding new elements to that list or manipulating existing

Tags: c#, list, xaml, binding, windows-phone

I have a problem with binding.
 Basically i have a list of objects. I bind a Long List Selector's DataSource to that list. For some strange reason I can't get the Long List Selector to show anything.
When my program runs it pulls a data from a Home Automation controller and passes it to the List. The process repeats for a while - pulling new data, adding to a list. At the same time I want the Long List Selector being updated every time new element is added to a list. So if I set the property which I am binding to at the first run every consecutive run is just adding a new element to that property which is a list basically or manipulating one of the elements in that list.
After an extensive troubleshooting I know that it is an issue with notification not the binding syntax. The way I figured it was: I set the break point at which I am reassigning a list I bounded to Long List Selector (at this point the List is full of elements) as DataSource of the Long List Selector and the Long List Selector showed all that data.

Here's my question: if I'm binding a DataSource to a `List<T>` where T is a complex object (with properties, other lists and other objects in it), and if I add element to that list or make a change to a property in one of the objects in that list, how do I notify the XAML about the change so it would update the Long List Selector? For all I know the List which I am binding to is the same object where underlying properties have changed (not the object itself) so this code is not going to work:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;

    }
```

I've read in some resources that it would be best to change a List of T to `ObservableCollection<T>` but could somebody tell me if I can do it with the List of T? I just want to understand it.

Thanks.

Edit: I have used an `ObservableCollection<T>` and it worked exactly the same as with `List<T>`- didn't update Long List Selector. 
Sometimes the smallest issue can bring the biggest headache - I'm struggling with this already for a week and can't seem to find a solution. The only way it works is when I create a new `List<T>` and fill it with objects from my model on every iteration which seems to me as a huge overkill. There is a small change in one of the objects at  every iteration - I feel there has to be a different, more efficient way to update just this small change instead of rewriting all other, not touched elements of that `List<T>`.
Please help.

Comment: Yes, you should really be using an `ObservableCollection<T>`, which is the collection type purposefully built for databinding. If you want to understand it then MSDN should nearly always be your first port of call ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I did use an ObservableCollection<T> and it didn't do it for me :/ Seems like each little item that is displayed in UI needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise PropertyChangedEvent.